# Custom Windows Fetures

Tags: windows, custom-controls, taskbar, windows-explorer

Is it possible to create custom windows features? for instance add new buttons to the start menu or maybe a button on the task bar like the Cortana button. Even add a new button to windows explorer. If it is can someone please point me in the right direction as google doesn't seem to return any helpful results

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom widgets on the taskbar by creating a [deskband shell extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144099(v=vs.85).aspx#desk_bands).

Creating a button in the start menu or in other places that have no extension support requires major work and will often create a buggy/unstable result because you might have to inject yourself into the Explorer desktop process (and other processes on Windows 10).